# HTML source code doesn't understand Arabic text?

Tags: php, html, encoding

I'm trying to read a source code for a webPage that contains Arabic text but all what am getting is this `&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593;&#1577;` (which is not Arabic, only a group of characters).

If I reload the page on my localhost I get the Arabic tags and text correctly.
But I really need to read that source code. any suggestions or lines of code I can add?

```
<html dir=rtl>

<META http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=windows-1256>
```

These are few lines from that include the "encoding" used! The page is written using **HTML** and **PHP**

Comment: Are there really spaces between the characters?

Comment: Actually I added them because if I keep it the way it is, you will be able to read Arabic words correctly which is not happening with the source code!

Comment: When you view the page source in a browser, do you see the Arabic characters or the character encodings you have posted?

Comment: the charachters I posted! Unless I press "inspect element" it shows them correctly !

Comment: Well, that's how they were coded in the source HTML then.

Comment: So I can't do anything to read it?!

Comment: The number is the HEX value of each character in the encoding of the page (probably UTF-8). You should be able to convert it back. I don't know PHP well enough to tell you how.

Comment: I didn't know `charset=windows-1256` supports arabic. But well, it's always interesting to see how things "evolve" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The characters are merely escaped to HTML entities. The browser decodes them to "real characters" when it renders the page. You can decode them yourself using [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
html_entity_decode('&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593;&#1577;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

Note the last parameter, which sets the encoding the characters will be decoded *to*. Use whatever encoding you're working with internally, I'm just suggesting UTF-8 here.

Comment: UTF-8 didn't work so I tried UTF-16 it converted it correctly  but am getting this warning:
 Warning: html_entity_decode() [function.html-entity-decode]: charset `UTF-16' not supported, assuming iso-8859-1 in C:\wamp\www\test2.php on line 10

Comment: But Actually am getting the same problem with the page source!

Comment: Please define "didn't work". What encoding *are* you using on your site?

Comment: It's not my site am trying to get the HTML source code from a website and the Arabic text is encoded in a way only the browser is able to read it!

Comment: It's not my site am trying to get the HTML source code from a website and the Arabic text is encoded in a way only the browser is able to read it!

Comment: @user I get that. And `html_entity_decode` allows you do decode those entities just like a browser would. The above will output Arabic text encoded in UTF-8. If that doesn't work for you, **tell me what "doesn't work" means!**